# Should I use try and accept in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am supposed to return a list of words based upon the last letter of the last word that is provided. I am having issues terminating when a word is not found when the last letter of the last word provided is not available. Like "e", if there are no words that start with the letter "e", it will not terminate the function and throw and error.

```
def game(names):
    words_by_letter = {}
    current_word = names[0]
    phrase = [current_word]
    lookup_letter = current_word[-1]
    for name in names:
        if name[0] in words_by_letter:
            words_by_letter[name[0]].append(name)
        else:
            words_by_letter[name[0]] = [name]

    while lookup_letter in words_by_letter:
        if lookup_letter[0]:
            next_word = words_by_letter[lookup_letter][0]
            phrase.append(next_word)
            del words_by_letter[current_word[0]][0]
            current_word = next_word
            lookup_letter = current_word[-1]
        else:
            break

    return phrase



print game(["bagon", "baltoy", "yamask", "starly", "nosepass", "kalob", "nicky", "booger"])
print game(["apple", "berry", "cherry"]) #should return ['apple']
print game(["noon", "naan", "nun"])
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement completely, but If want to handle the error being thrown and terminate, look into [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions)

Comment: Can your provide a few sample inputs/outputs for better understanding of the problem. As it is written, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Also, your code does a lot in one function. Try to split it into short, stupidly simple functions that do one simple thing each. It is harder for an error to hide in a very short and simple piece of code. You will be able to run and test each function separately. When you run a whole game, you, for instance, don't see the intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag in while loop.

```
flag = False

while lookup_letter in words_by_letter:
    if lookup_letter[0]:
        next_word = words_by_letter[lookup_letter][0]
        phrase.append(next_word)
        del words_by_letter[current_word[0]][0]
        current_word = next_word
        lookup_letter = current_word[-1]
        flag=True # Here if found it sets flag to true
    else:
        break
if flag:
    return phrase
```